# dynamically change CSS on window resize using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window-resize

I'm building a restaurant menu system whereby the chosen menu slides over on click.

Everything's working correctly, however, I'm now trying to make it dynamically resize with the window.

Having massive difficulty with this, my jQuery is coming along well, but hit a wall...

**jQuery**

```
var $mmenu = $('.menu__main');

if ($mmenu.length > 0) {

    var $mnav = $('.menu__nav'),
        $mnav_a = $mnav.find('a'),
        m = parseInt($mnav.outerHeight(true), 10),
        $contain = $mmenu.closest('.menu-container'),
        h = 0,
        l = 0;

    $mmenu.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    $mmenu.eq(0).addClass('active');
    $mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');

    $mmenu.each(function(z) {

        var $this = $(this),
            $mmenuHeight;

        $(window).smartresize(function () {
            $mmenuHeight = parseInt($this.outerHeight(true), 10) + m;
        });

        $this.css('height','auto');

        $this.css({
            zIndex: z+1,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: m + "px",
            left: l,
            height: $mmenuHeight + "px"
        });

        l = l - $this.outerWidth();

    });

    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        $contain.height($mmenu.eq(0).height());
    });

}

$(window).trigger("smartresize");
```

The two `$(window).smartresize()` functions are incorrectly used I know, so any guidance on this would be appreciated. the first is setting the height for the individual menus, the second for the menu container.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using media queries instead of jQuery to do this?

Comment: I have but the client has full control over menus, both the amount present and the content on them. It needs to be something that changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using media queries for this sort of work. It's easier and is widely supported. I am unsure why you need to position absolutely all the menu items. You can accomplish sliding out functionality using hover in combination with relative positioning or transforms. This way you dont need to worry so much about setting individual heights.

As a side note, will the web application's function to be resized on the fly or only on initial load?

**DOCS**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries

Your code might look something like

```
@media screen and (max-width:/* your desired breakpoint*/) {
     .menu li {
          width:100%;
          max-width:/* the maximum size that you want you menu item to be */
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm a big user of media queries, and I am using them for aspects of the build. But it's the menu height that needs to set dynamically, not the width. To put it into context, one menu may be 400px, another 1500px, and I need to animate between them on click

Comment: Hm, can you add a screenshot maybe I can help :) If you remove the height value and make the items block it should calculate the height of the content no?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.. The way the menu system is built, height has to be declared, unfortunately it needs to change on the fly :) Screen in the main question for you

Comment: it works perfectly if I wrap the lot in the function $(window).smartresize(function () { }); but then if you're on menu with :eq(1) or greater, it breaks